# I'm trying to run a java file, but I'm getting an error with the List<Row> and it's saying that the type "Row" does not exist. What can I do?

Tags: java

[Attached below is the code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nnIr.png)

I tried to create an empty class called `Row.java` that VSCode suggested, but the issues with `getWaitingTime()`, `getProcessName()`, `getTurnaroundTime()` aren't resolved. Any advice?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! It is against the guidelines to provide source code as an image link. Please copy and paste the code in the question instead and use the appropriate formatting to make it clear!

Comment: You need to add those methods into your class `Row`. 

For more details, you can research getters (and setters) in Java, and how they work.

Comment: You're using a class called Row.  Presumably it's supposed to *mean* something and *do* something.  Providing an empty class satisfies the requirements that Row exists but does not provide anything meaningful.  Where did you get this "java file" from?  It seems like you only got part of a program.

Comment: Another possible reason is that you missing a dependency on another Java library.

Comment: You should fix the indentation of your source code so you can easily see which code blocks starts and ends where.